# Laravel 5.8 Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Verified' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, email-verification

So I have an Laravel app, but I have overridden the default `sendEmailVerificationNotification` function in my `App\User.php`. Because I didn't want the default email thing.

Now, when I register, I get an email and activation etc... That all works perfectly. However, when I click the link, I get a 500 error... So I go and look into the logs and see the follwoing error:

`Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Verified' not found`

Now, indeed, that class doesn't exist, because I have no idea what I should do in that class...

In my `User.php`, the `verify` method is the following;

```
public function verify(Request $request): Response
{
    if ($request->route('id') != $request->user()->getKey()) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }
    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
    if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($request->user()));
        toastr()->success('Uw email is geverifiëerd', 'Gelukt!', ['timeOut' => 5000]);
    }
    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
}
```

The full error is this:

> [2019-04-14 11:57:29] staging.ERROR: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Verified' not found
>   {"userId":3,"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Verified' not found at
>   /var/www/rpr/releases/20190414113903/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/VerificationController.php:60)

Line 60 in `VerficationController.php` is the `}` of the if-statement with `hasVerifiedEmail`.

Can someone please explain how I can just verify the user and give a notification that the account has been verified?

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `Auth` facade. Add this line to your controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add Verified class to your use, then add:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
```